# Mapping SQL Server integer to Oracle Datatype

Tags: sql-server, oracle, datatypes

Well I know, that an SQL Server integer is best represented by NUMBER(10).

But sometimes I have migrate some maintenance scripts to Oracle and I wonder if I must carefully 
map integer to NUMBER(10) or if I can just use the ansi type integer in Oracle.

Is there any reason not to use integer?

**EDIT:**

I verified it against 10g.

```
create table BK_int_test(
i_col integer,
f_col float);

insert into BK_int_test values (1, 1);
insert into BK_int_test values (1.1, 1.1);

Select * from BK_int_test;
```

and got

```
     I_COL      F_COL
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1        1,1

2 rows selected.
```

Thanks that saves a lot of work.

The short form `int` of `integer` is supported as well.

Comment: will you ever be porting `integer` data back to SQL Server from Oracle from those fields?

Comment: In this special case no. But generally We (the developers) always hope that the Oracle database administrator of our customers retire and we can migrate the house to SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any reason to not use `integer` in Oracle. It will be mapped to the approriate Oracle datatype but keeps the DDL at least somewhat portable.

I also always use VARCHAR instead of VARCHAR2 as they are equivalent anyway. Oracle does not recommend this, as in the future this might change, but this has been true since version 6, so I doubt that it will actually change at all ;)

Comment: I'm not sure, if I follow you with respect to varchar. It is a rather simple text replacement. But keeping the number types in sync is a real advantage.

Comment: @bernd - I think the reference to `varchar` is because `integer` [isn't an Oracle type](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#sthref241), but it is fine to use it as they will never remove the mapping to `number(38)`. Just like they will never remove `varchar` despite the long-standing threat.

Comment: I asked this question because the internet sources,  didn't state explicitly that an constraint to true integers is enforced. But I checked that point.

Answer (score 2):

The only two reasons I can think of for not just using `integer` are:

1. If you plan on porting integer data back to SQL Server from Oracle from those fields at some point: if integers out of the range [-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) have been inserted on the Oracle side, these values will overflow on the return journey
2. If some part of an application is relying on integers being in the aforementioned range. Values outside this range might therefore cause an error

Neither of these potential problems would be resolved by using `number(10)` which allows integers in the range [-9,999,999,999 to 9,999,999,999](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#sthref120). If it is necessary to constrain the integers to the same range, it would be better to use a `check constraint`, eg:

```
alter table my_table add check (val between -2147483648 and 2147483647);
```

Comment: The only practical problems I encountered so far, occurred  when porting back from Oracle to SQL-Server are with date to dateime when used to contain time only values. But migration back is the exception.